# grails validate email customized message

Tags: validation, email, grails, customization

I wanted to customized the error message for email validation when it fails the constraint:

```
email(size: 1..255, blank: false, email:true)
```

this displays message like this:

> Property [email] of class [class
>   com.companyname.icmgrails.nonpersistentdomains.UserProfile] with value
>   [eulinda] is not a valid e-mail address

I could not figure out how to use that and put it in my **messages.properties** like the example below when email is blank.

> com.companyname.icmgrails.nonpersistentdomains.UserProfile.email.blank=Email
>   should not be blank!

tried solutions:

> I used
>   [com.companyname.icmgrails.nonpersistentdomains.UserProfile.email] 
>   + notavalidemail or notvalid or notavalidemaladdress or notvalidemaladdress

but was unsucessfull. ANyone can tell me how to use it? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every constraint specifies the required message code on its reference page in the user guide.  In the case of [the email constraint](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/email.html) you need

```
com.companyname.icmgrails.nonpersistentdomains.UserProfile.email.email.invalid=Not a valid email address
```

Comment: the answer you gave did not work but helped me in coming up with the correct answer. it should be com.companyname.icmgrails.nonpersistentdomains.UserProfile.email.email.invalid. turns out the email property should still be there aside from the email.invalid.

Comment: @user742102 thanks, I've corrected it now, not sure why I didn't spot this comment sooner.